# How to use renovate and gitlab-ci to keep package.json updated

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How can I use renovate and gitlab-ci.yml to keep package.json updated? I want to automatically check for updates of my package.json packages twice a day and if there are, create a merge request for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

[The renovate documentation](https://docs.renovatebot.com/install-gitlab-app/) explains how to set up on GitLab.com.

Renovate runs as the user `@renovate-bot` on gitlab.com.

To enable the hosted WhiteSource Renovate App on your GitLab.com project, you can do any of the following:

- Add @renovate-bot as a Developer directly to each project
- or Add @renovate-bot to a team that has Developer access to the project
- Install using the WhiteSource Renovate Dashboard's UI

Comment: I read that, but it's not clear for me and I also need the gitlab-ci.yml config file.

Comment: @user9086883 if you have already tried it, can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: Friendly reminder: I added `renovate-bot` as a developer. The second day I got an incoming call from an unknown number with +44 prefix - did not accept it. Just after it, I got an email from Renovate that they want to make a 20-minute call with me and product specialist. Very surprised and disappointed.

Comment: Renovate Bot on gitlab has been recently suspended due to security concerns.  https://github.com/renovatebot/app-support/issues/106